# How to use ABSwitchCluster to failover between Kafka clusters

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have an application that is using Kafka to Synchronize data between instances, therefore it both produces and consumes data from Kafka, additionally the application is consuming a Kafka Topic and transforming and streaming that data into another topic for clients to consume.

My Application has two Clusters for failover.  Going through the Kafka Documentation I found this
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#connecting that talks about `ABSwitchCluster`.

How can I use [ABSwitchCluster](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/2.5.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/kafka/core/ABSwitchCluster.html) to Failover Automagically if the Kafka Cluster goes down, for both `KafkaTemplate.send()` and `@KafkaListener` annotated methods?

---

**Update with More Info**

I've added some error Handlers for KafkaTemplate.send and Kafka Consumer Events `NonResponsiveConsumerEvent` and `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`

Ultimately they call a shared Method to switch, and a `BeanPostProcessor` is used to actually add the `ABSwitchCluster` to `KafkaResourceFactory` Beans.

The Switch over code looks like so:

```
   @Autowired
   KafkaSwitchCluster kafkaSwitchCluster;

   @Autowired
   WebApplicationContext context;

   @Autowired
   KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

   /**
    *  Unable to use {@link Autowired} due to circular dependency
    *  with {@link KafkaPostProcessor}
    *  @return
    */
   public DefaultKafkaProducerFactory getDefaultKafkaProducerFactory()
   { return context.getBean(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.class); }

   /** Back-End Method to Actually Switch between the clusters */
   private void switchCluster()
   {
      if (kafkaSwitchCluster.isPrimary()) { kafkaSwitchCluster.secondary(); }
      else { kafkaSwitchCluster.primary(); }

      getDefaultKafkaProducerFactory().reset();

      registry.stop();
      registry.destroy();
      registry.start();

      for(MessageListenerContainer listener : registry.getListenerContainers() )
      {
         listener.stop();
         listener.start();
      }
   }
```

Given the Updates Above when Looking in the Test Logs, it appears that the Producer is correctly, switching clusters, but my consumers are not.

So how can I get the `@KafkaListener` consumers to switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default producer and consumer factories as well as the `KafkaAdmin` are suclasses of `KafkaResourceFactory`.

You pass the `ABSwitchCluster` in by calling `setBootstrapServersSupplier()`.

The `ABSwitchCluster` does not fail over automatically.

You need your own code to perform the failover and then call `reset()` on the producer factory and stop/start all the listener containers (`KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop()/start()` for all `@KafkaListener`s.

Comment: Thank you for answering, It helped verify some things I was already trying and gave me a direction. Can you please help with my update.

Comment: You don't need to stop/start the registry AND the containers - the registry does that. Stopping and starting the containers should work, as long as you have not overridden the bootstrap server property at the `@KafkaListener` level (which overrides the factory setting), which is rare. I'll take a look...

Comment: It works fine for me - I just added a [test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/d6a17b5e4cbc95e736744a9a486e0292604dbaed/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ABSwitchClusterTests.java#L52-L127) to verify the correct operation. If you still can't get it to work, try to create a stripped down small project that exhibits the behavior, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Looks like what I did wrong was,  switching the cluster then `stop()/start()` instead of 1. `stop()`  2. switch 3.  `start()`  **Ordering is important.**