# Spring Bookt Kafka ABSwitchCluster

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I couldn't find any example to swtich between kafka cluster .

Anyone has implmeneted this class **ABSwitchCluster** from Spring Kafka.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/

I tried with below code, but its not switching cluster.

```
@RestController
public class ApacheKafkaWebController {

    @Autowired
    ConsumerKakfaConfiguration configuration;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @Autowired
    private ABSwitchCluster switcher;

    @GetMapping(value = "/switch")
    public String producer() {

        registry.stop();
        switcher.secondary();
        registry.start();
        return "switched!";
    }

}
```

and swticher bean here:

```
 @Bean
    public ABSwitchCluster switcher() {
        return new ABSwitchCluster("127.0.0.1:9095", "127.0.0.1:9096");
    }
```

Could you please tell me am I missing anything here?, still its running in 9095 port.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937929/how-to-use-abswitchcluster-to-failover-between-kafka-clusters/62938563#62938563) and [this test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/949263851c821e809dfe132ed18ef2ba22a74d77/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ABSwitchClusterTests.java#L56-L75).

Basically, you switch the cluster and reset the connections by stopping and starting listener containers and resetting the producer factory.

Comment: Just defining it as a `@Bean` does nothing; you have to add it to the consumer and/or producer factory. See `setBootstrapServersSupplier()`.

Comment: Since you are using Spring Boot; if you are using its auto-configured factories, add them as parameters to your `switcher` bean definition method and call the setter(s) before returning the switcher. e.g. `... switcher(ConsumerFctory<?, ?> cf) {...}`.

Comment: Your suggestion helped me!